# Compile GWT closure error

Tags: gwt, closures

I get below error when compiling. How to find out which file affected and cause this error?

```
   splitPointToFragmentMap[38] = 16
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:28 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass process
         [ERROR] INFO: processGoogScopeAliases
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:28 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass process
         [ERROR] INFO: processProvidesAndRequires
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:29 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass process
         [ERROR] INFO: checkVars
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:29 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass process
         [ERROR] INFO: checkRegExp
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:30 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass process
         [ERROR] INFO: renameCssNames
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:30 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass process
         [ERROR] INFO: replaceMessages
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:30 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.PhaseOptimizer$NamedPass process
         [ERROR] INFO: processDefines
         [ERROR] Nov 19, 2012 2:33:31 AM com.google.gwt.thirdparty.javascript.jscomp.Compiler normalize
         [ERROR] INFO: Normalizing
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have a `.js` includes which gwt closure compiler option is trying to optimize and is reporting an error.

Steps to solve gwt closure compiler error messages.

1) Set compiler loglevel to `TRACE`

2) Set compiler flag strict to `true`

Compile and verify whether any additional information is found. Also iteratively remove any js includes or third party jar to isolate which is the offending jar.

Note: To make this more challenging GWT compileReport,compilerMetrics,soycDetailed do not function when GWT Closure Compiler is turned on http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7475